# How to properly include Qt5Core static library, with using CMake in android studio project?

Tags: android, c++, qt, cmake, libraries

I have problem when I link **C++ static library** in android studio. It is **Native C++ android studio project** and static library is linked.

The static library depends on **Qt5Core** library, so I have also included the needed library **libQt5Core.a** for all ABI, same way like my library:

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_library(Qt5Core STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(Qt5Core PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libQt5Core.a)
```

I placed my headers from the library in `app\src\main\cpp\include`.  And I included them in **native-lib.cpp** file:

```
#include "include/MyLib/testingclass.h"
```

And the problem is that I get error: `fatal error: 'QList' file not found`

Because I am using it in my library like this:

```
 #include <QList>
```

I am beginner at CMake and I think that I need to include the header files from **QtCore** in my project. Thanks in advance.

**I have tried to solve it like this:**

I have copied `C:\Qt\5.13.1\android_static\include\Qt5Core` in this location `app\src\main\cpp\include` and I changed `#include <QList>` to  `#include "include/QtCore/QList"` but still got error that can't be found.

**UPDATE:**
Another try instead of linking the static library, I tried this which still give QList not found error:

```
set(Qt5_DIR "C:\\Qt\\5.13.1\\android_static\\lib\\cmake\\Qt5\\")
set(Qt5Core_DIR "C:\\Qt\\5.13.1\\android_static\\lib\\cmake\\Qt5Core\\")
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
```